# how to get the users id's on after select checkbox from fieldset using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using this code to select the checbox from fieldset:

```
$("fieldset:has(input[type='checkbox'])")
```

its working fine on the fieldset I have studentid's I need to get the student id's which ever textbox is selected on the fieldset?

Can anybody help me out?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("fieldset input[name=theName]:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
    alert(this.value);
});
```